# Systematic way of choosing a threshold?

Tags: r, statistical-significance, dataset, data-mining, threshold

I am performing some analysis on understanding various characteristics of a certain population. To narrow down my selection (as I will be going through them manually), I am using different thresholds on certain measurable properties (which tell me how relevant someone is) to draw the following frequency graph. For instance, the line marked `Threshold 1` tells me that when I fix my threshold at `t1`, there are approximately 360 people with at least 1 friend, 290 people with at least 2 friends etc.

I am aware that I will be having a hard time explaining what I am doing but I will try my best. I am trying to fix two thresholds: one that is used to obtain the line and the other that I use to filter noise. The '0' on the graph marks the thresholds. In this particular case, I am using `Threshold 3` and filtering my population to contain only those people that have `>= 2 friends`. While this is working well for me, I am trying to determine if there is systematic procedure to explain why these thresholds are better than others. For instance, `Threshold 2` is not such a good filter because it behaves like `Threshold 1`. Utilizing `Threshold 4` is not so useful because the returns in going from `Threshold 2` to `Threshold 3` is much higher than that going from `Threshold 3` to `Threshold 4`.

Any suggestions on where I should start? Basically, I want to do something similar to cost-benefit analysis (that's the closest I could think off).

[image]

Comment: What is the point of the threshold? Are you just trying to maximize the "#people" for any given threshold?

Comment: Related to Andy's comment, the need for a threshold was not motivated.  Estimating the relationship between the two variables using a suitable model and not assuming linearity would seem to be in order.

Comment: @Andy W: That is correct. For a given threshold and (# of friends), I am trying to find a good point where I can stop and inspect the resulting data.

Comment: @Frank Harrell: My apologies for that. The threshold in some indirect sense indicates the influence level of a person. Threshold 1 gets me a curve where I don't care about whether or not a person could have influence on others. Threshold 2 indicates that I am narrowing down the population to only those that have at least α influence. This value was calculate from some other

Comment: From that it seems that a probability estimate is needed, or an estimate of the expected number of people influenced, as a function of the number of friends.  I'm still not seeing the need for a threshold but I may be missing your premise.